# Clear Format of All Valued cells Dim Range VBA Issue

Tags: vba

I just started coding a few days back and am trying to use all `dim` variables, since that's what everyone has been saying to use. So, I am trying to clear formats using current region (basically all cells containing value or formatting). Here is my code and I get a compile error and `VBA` highlights the "Entire' portion of the last code. Any thoughts? I'm new and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
Sub ClearFormatting()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim Entire As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Entire = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ws.entire.ClearFormats
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ClearFormatting()

    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim Entire As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set Entire = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Entire.ClearFormats 'no ws.

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your response! However, how do I specify what worksheet it goes to if I have multiple? I don't want to to clear all worksheets just 'ws'...

Comment: Entire is a Range object pointing to the UsedRange on ws.  If you call the ClearFormats method on that Range then only that range is affected.